# Get tag name from its attribute name

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have an array like this:

```
["school_name":"My School Name", "school_number":"54546", "note":"", "class":1]
```

and HTML like this:

```
<input type="text" name="school_name" />
<input type="text" name="school_number" />
<textarea name="note" ></textarea>
<select name="class">
    <option value="1"> One </option>
    <option value="2"> Two </option>
    <option value="3"> Three </option>
</select>
```

I want to get a tag's name from its attribute name:

```
$('*[name=school_name]').attr("tag"); // this is input
$('*[name=class]').attr("tag"); // this is select
$('*[name=note]').attr("tag"); // this is textarea
```

**Note** that I have tried this:

```
$('*[name=school_name]').attr("tag");
$('*[name=school_name]').prop("tag");
$('*[name=school_name]').get(0).tagName;
$('*[name=school_name]')[0].tagName;
```

This is what I want to do:

If the tag name is input text,

```
$("input[name=school_name]").attr("value", "My School Name");
```

If the tag name is a select box,

```
$("select[name=class]").children("option[value=2]").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var schoolProperties = {
    "school_name": "My School Name",
    "school_number": "54546",
    "note": "",
    "class": 1
};
for (var property in schoolProperties) {
    $('*[name=' + property + ']').attr('value', schoolProperties[property]);
}
```

​This is demonstrated in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcPRW/).

Comment: Because i wasn't know that `select , textarea` can selected by value

Answer (score 2):

If I got what you're looking for then you need to use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('[name=school_number]').filter("input");
$('[name=class]').filter("select");
$('[name=note]').filter("textarea");
```

Comment: +1 Although this doesn't answer the direct question of how to get the tag name, I believe this may be the best solution to the OP's use case.

Comment: My Form contain many inputs ,textareas and select   and i can't know is this name refer to input or select or textarea

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.6, you want to use $xxxxx.prop("tagName")

Comment: I'm using Version 1.7.2 , Can You add example Because i tried it and result is undefiened

Comment: alert($("*[name='school_name']").prop("tagName")); - This displays "INPUT" for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute [`.nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.nodeName) to determine the tag name of an element

Comment: Thank You For help , But @creemama Answer Less code and very useful for me

Answer (score 1):

You had the correct way to do it. [Both of these work:](http://jsfiddle.net/ecjvC/)

```
$('*[name=school_name]').get(0).tagName;
$('*[name=school_name]')[0].tagName;
```

You can also remove the `*` and you may want to convert the `tagName` to lowercase first or at least a consistent case:

```
var $el = $('[name=school_name]');
var tagName;
if($el.length)
    tagName = $el[0].tagName

if(tagName)
    tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
```